# How to launch an application from the browser in BlackBerry

Tags: browser, blackberry

How do I launch the installed application on a device from the BlackBerry browser? My application details:

Without login credentials the user cannot have further access to the application, so on application start there are two buttons, one for registration and other for logging in. Here is how it has to work.

1. The unregistered user starts the application, and clicks the registration button.
2. Invoke the BlackBerry browser with the registration URL.
3. The user completes the registration process and on successful registration the page will have a link to the launch application.

Are there any possibilities in BlackBerry for this? It is possible on the iPhone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Give any unique link on your web page, for example www.example.com
2. register httpfilter in your application,

   HttpFilterRegistry.registerFilter("www.example.com", "com.sample.filter");
3. "com.sample.filter" is a package in which you have to create the Protocol.java class to handle the call back.

For more information, check the "HTTPFilterDemo" sample included with the BlackBerry JDE.

Comment: Hi virat, thanks for ur reply. As i seen that HTTPFilterDemo but i dint able to understand action of protocol class, could u pleas explain it more. One more thing i need similar functionality as it able to do in iPhone. Ex: In my application i will register the one unique url and say i closed app, opened the browser and will type the same registered url on browser then browser should able to launch the my app.