# Launching Blackberry Application via a Custom URL Scheme

Tags: blackberry

I'm working on RIM HttpFilterRegistry part. Can anyone explain on how to embed (protocol & packageManager class) in a native app with an UI entry point.

Requirement:

1. To Launch native 3rd party app when a url from BB browser is selected.
2. Can the registration be done at app installation if permitted or by an alternate entry point

A bit confused on how to implement the HttpFilterRegistry class.

There's little help on BB docs though :(.

There's a similar thread on the forum
[How to launch an application from the browser in BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568503/how-to-launch-an-application-from-the-browser-in-blackberry)

Answer (score 2):

You don't implement the `HttpFilterRegistry` class yourself, you use the one that RIM provides.  Just call `HttpFilterRegistry.registerFilter()` like any other API call.  What you do have to implement yourself is a java package that includes a class named `Protocol`.  You then pass the package name to `registerFilter()`, and the browser will then access your `Protocol` class when the registered domain is invoked.

Comment: Thanks Remy for the quick one,... 

I see 2 protocol classes in the demo provided. Just need ur help if m moving in correct direction

Say if I register as
HttpFilterRegistry.registerFilter("www.testPage.com", "com.asb.test.httpfilter.precanned", true);

What exactly protocol class include apart from the PAGE_DATA i.e the html page(www.testpage.com) 
so the browser understands there is a need to invoke app

Comment: You can only have one `Protocol` class in the package you specify.  In the demo, it has two packages and registers two URLs. The `na.blackberry.com` URL invokes the `com.rim.samples.device.httpfilterdemo.precanned.Protocol` class, and the `www.rim.com` URL invokes the `com.rim.samples.device.httpfilterdemo.filter.Protocol` class. In your case, `www.testPage.com` would invoke the `com.asb.test.httpfilter.precanned.Protocol` class.

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

Tried the above steps for getting the app active but in vain :( ... What more need to be configured in the protocol class so there is an auto invoke for my native app. I still can't get the concept clear for this..

    Your help is much more needed...

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?  Please update your question with your actual code.  Does your `Protocol` class implement the `FilterBaseInterface` and `HttpConnection` interfaces?