# Launch BlackBerry WebWorks PhoneGap app via URL with parameters?

Tags: url, blackberry, cordova, query-string

I have a WebWorks PhoneGap app that I would like to launch from a browser URL, and pass URL query parameters to the app that way.  Can this be done?  How?  I would be happy to [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165519/launching-blackberry-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme) [HttpFilterRegistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568503/how-to-launch-an-application-from-the-browser-in-blackberry) or the [Invoke API](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.invoke.html), but I don't see how to use those approaches to obtain the parameters from within my WebWorks app, even if I write a custom extension.  [PhoneGap/Cordova](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/) may have a solution as well, but I can't find it.  Sample code would be very helpful, especially for consuming the parameters.  Or at least an indication of which API(s) can do this.

Comment: I received an answer from Ranaman on the BlackBerry dev forums [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Launch-BlackBerry-WebWorks-app-via-URL-with-parameters/m-p/1674663).  But I have yet to confirm that it actually works.