# blackberry detect imei no. when any link is clicked

Tags: php, blackberry, imei

How can I get the IMEI number when user clicks on a link form his/her blackberry? Maybe I can pass data to a php. Can somebody throw some light on how can I achieve this? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: i don't think thats even remotely possible

Comment: if you get the click event, then you can use my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will programatically get the imei number.

```
private String getIMEINumber() {

  byte[] imeiByteArray = net.rim.device.api.system.GPRSInfo.getIMEI();

  String imei = net.rim.device.api.system.GPRSInfo.imeiToString(imeiByteArray);

  imeiByteArray = null;

  return imei;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know this. But what I want to do is that when the user clicks on a link then I could get his/her Imei no. This should be possible in some way. Can anybody help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: is it possible to get the click event of url?

Comment: inside your app or third party app ?

Comment: link can be in any browser or mail

Comment: so you have to know wether the user is clicked the link or not. Is it possible to get that ?

Comment: i dont know wether its possible to get the click event.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22164/discussion-between-signare-and-nikita-sharma)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the IMEI without handling it in your own application.

One way would be to write an application that can handle a custom url. See this: [How to launch an application from the browser in BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4568717/1052358)

Your application could essentially handle this in the background.